# Htaccess rewritting non www to www /and/ domain.tld/id to domaine.tld/page.php?id=

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't find solution to do 2 things on my htaccess for my domain :

1/ -> Redirect https://domain.tld to https://www.domaine.tld (index.php)

2/ -> Url rewritting to have url like **https://www.domaine.tld/id** witch call  https://www.domain.tld/page.php?id=

My htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirection page.php?id=
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)?$ /page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

With this htaccess I'm redirected to page.php?id=$1 but if I try to go on index I'm always redirected to page.php
I know the 2 conditions are the same but I don't know how could I fix it.

An idea ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Replace `^([0-9a-zA-Z\-]+?)?$` with `^/?(id)` or something like that, not clear what you are capturing there.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown attempts, please try following rules in htaccess file. Make sure your htaccess file is residing along with index.php, page.php files.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##External redirect with www attached in url.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

##Internal rewrite for home pages.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [QSA,L]

##Internal rewrite for non-existing pages.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ page.php=$1 [QSA,L]
```